# ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de utilizar SCSS en Angular?

Tags: angular, scss

Tengo un proyecto el cual comencé con `ng new proyecto --routing --style=scss` para poder utilizar SCSS.

La estructura de mi proyecto es algo como esto:

```
src/
..app/
....componentes/
......componente1
......componente2
....servicios/
......servicio1
....shared/
......componente1
......componente2
..assets/
....img/
....scss/
......base/
........archivo.scss
......utilities/
........archivo.scss
......main.scss
..styles.scss
```

Dentro del archivo `assets/scss/main.scss` importo los archivos que tengo en los directorios de SCSS. Ejemplo:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import "base/index";
@import "utilities/index";
```

Dentro de `base/index` tengo algo como:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import "colores.scss";
@import "fonts.scss";
```

Dentro de colores.scss tengo variables como `$rojo: red;`.

Esto funciona bien, pero cuando quiero comenzar a escribir código scss de algún componente; por ejemplo, el `src/componentes/componente1/componente1.scss` tengo que comenzar el archivo importando el archivo `src/styles.scss`

Lo que me deja algo como esto:

```
@import '../../../styles.scss';
```

Mi problema es que si tengo más niveles en mis directorios tengo que cambiar los `/../` para que pueda utilizar el archivo. [Leí en este enlace que se puede utilizar algo como lo siguiente](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli):

```
@import '~sass/variables';
```

(Pero no me funciona) Me gustaría utilizar algo similar, para no tener que importar el archivo `src/styles.scss` en cada una de mis hojas de estilo, o por lo menos no tener que preocuparme de la ruta con `/../`.

Comment: ¿Tienes el archivo importado en el angular.json?

Comment: Lo intenté pero tampoco me funcionó ¿Lo tendría que hacer por ahí?

Comment: Normalmente los archivos de estilos siempre deben ir bajo el array `styles` y siempre de ultimo, eso es porque asi evitamos utilizar la eliminación del Encapsulación de Vistas. Si no hay otro remedio, propongo que leas sobre `:host::ng-deep`, aunque deprecados, funcionales.

Comment: Lo voy a checar. Muchas gracias.